# Firestore Indexes - for each UserID or UID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, indexing, userid

I am creating task entries by Firestore User.ID or UID..For every new User.ID collection...i get an error message that says a index has to be created by that particular User.ID which is not feasible given that in my solution i can have any number of users...cannot be running back to create an index for each user

[Individual Index by UserID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OcFO.png)

Trying desperately to find a solution...i thought right or otherwise that i have to create a Single Field Exemption for User.UID...which i did as shown below BUT it does not work....My query is by User.ID on the field priority.....What is worse...i now cannot delete that Single Field Exemption...when i click on it...it is highlighted but no menu option appears...

[Single Field Exemption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmTXJ.png)

Any idea how to delete it and more importantly how to not have to create an index for each User.ID...As normal...Googles documentation is totally useless .....it does not answer to specific situations.

## Affected Entries

[Example Affected Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veCXv.png)
When an authenticated user enters a task document...it records their UUID as a new entry (marked in RED) and associated documents...Every time a new entry is made for a new user....it is not updated but an error message is obtained that says index needs to be created ..the index id is the user UID.  It asks for every new user...

Comment: To understand better. You only need to be capable to get a single user from a `users` collection, based on the ID of the users that comes from the authentication mechanism, without the need for an index? What's the programming language you're using?

Comment: I've added a bit more information - see Affected Entries at the bottom of my entry.  I am programming in Python for Google Apps Engine, Swift UI and Android for the associated mobile apps...The new user is registered in the mobile apps and monitored by the admin using Google Apps Engine

Comment: Brilliant....you are a Google Developer Expert from Firebase.....it is like i am a priest talking to Jesus....so to speak...

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this ????